# Pivot con Oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

En esta consulta, día es un campo fecha, esfuerzo un campo numérico donde guardo el numero de horas trabajadas y técnico, pues el nombre del técnico. Quiero sacar las horas por cada mes de cada técnico.

```
select * from 
(
select to_char(dia, 'yyyymm'), tecnico, esfuerzo
from seguimiento_diario
) 
pivot
(
sum(esfuerzo) for to_char(dia, 'yyyymm') in (select to_char(dia, 'yyyymm') from seguimiento_diario)
) 
order by tecnico
```

Comment: te recomiendo leer esto [pivot](http://mundodb.es/oracle-pivot-oracle-unpivot)

Comment: gracias por el link :)